# How to create MySQL function to create a new column of quarter by processing existing column of date?

Tags: mysql, function

I have a column Date as shown below:

```
+-----------+
|   Date    |
+-----------+
|  20140611 |
|  20150119 |
|  20150922 |
|  20160310 |
+-----------+
```

It's a string in `YYYYMMDD` format.

I want to create a new column named `Quarter` as shown below:

```
+-----------+-------------+
|   Date    |   Quarter   |
+-----------+-------------+
|  20140611 |  Q2-2014    |
|  20150119 |  Q1-2015    |
|  20150922 |  Q3-2015    |
|  20160310 |  Q3-2016    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

where `Quarter` indicates a quarter in which the corresponding `Date` falls.

This is just for example purpose, but I actually want to know how can I write a function which can be applied on a single column of a table to create a new column after some pre-defined processing.

Comment: It's just for an example purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have made the necessary changes. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use quarter function

```
select `Date`, QUARTER(`date`) as Quarter
from my_table ;
```

otherwise if you are looking for user defined function you can use

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world(my_text TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT
    LANGUAGE SQL -- This element is optional and will be omitted from    
    BEGIN
     RETURN CONCAT('Hello ', my_text);
   END;
    $$
  DELIMITER ;
```

then

```
SELECT hello_world('Earth');
```

return   Hello Earth

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it has an inbuilt function `QUARTER`. Though I am looking for a general way to write function (so that I will be able to tweak it as per needed, in future).

Comment: Take  look ad this for reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html .. hope my answer is useful

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. The link you provided is very much useful but unfortunately, the definition of a quarter in my example won't be a standard one. Actually I will consider min-date to fall in first quarter, and will continue calculating quarters for other dates.

Comment: @Sangram Consider amending your question accordingly, but note that you wouldn't normally store derived data.

Comment: Anyway i have update the answer adding create function  udf ref